# AWS IAM Cloudformation error: "Syntax error at position (Service: AmazonIdentityManagement; Status Code: 400; Error Code: MalformedPolicyDocument

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam

```yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: ' '

Parameters:
    ExternalAccount:
        Type: String
        Description: Enter the external account whicg

Resources:
  NewRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Principal:
              - AWS: "arn:aws:s3:::${ExternalAccount}:root"
            
          Action:
              - sts:AssumeRole
      ManagedPolicyArns:
      - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonKinesisReadOnlyAccess
      - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonDynamoDBFullAccess
      - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/CloudWatchFullAccess
```

Comment: What are you trying to do ?

Comment: You forgot a `!Sub`. It should be `- AWS: !Sub "arn:aws:s3:::${ExternalAccount}:root"`